# How to get a modal window to pop out of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm new to web coding so forgive me if this is a dumb question/ awkward wording.

I'm trying to get a dialogue in the child page to pop out of the confines the an iframe into the parent page (hosting the iframe). So the resulting of the modal would overlap the elements on the parent page.

I've tried $('.modalwindow').appendTo: $(window.parent.document).find('body'), which is not working.

Here's what I have so far, and it doesn't seem to work either. child.html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="btn">Open Me</button>
        <div class="modalwindow">
            <iframe id="apple" src""></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script> 
        $(".modalwindow").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            closeText: "",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 600,
            //dialogClass: "no-close",
            //dialogClass: "theme",
            //zIndex: $.maxZIndex()+ 1,
            open: function(ev, ui){
             $('#apple').attr('src','http://www.nytimes.com');}
        });
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            $('.modalwindow').dialog('open');
        });
$(".modalwindow").appendTo: $(top.document.body); // Not working, and messes up dialog. 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a cross-domain JavaScript issue. Here are three possible scenarios:

1. Domains of the host-page and nested page coincide - than you can get access to the contents of other page and even initialize the popup in the host page from the child one (but this obviously doesn't work).
2. Domain of the host-page and nested page differ,  but you have access to both domains. Than you can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage or try to use some JS libraries like this one http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro
   By using above-mentioned approaches you will have to create two scripts, one for host page and one for child page. Child page script will ask host page script to actually show the popup. And host-page script will do the job. When popup is closed host page script can send event or execute call-back function to inform child page about changes.
3. Domains are different and you don't have access to one of them. Sorry that is the worst case. Due to security reasons you won't be able to solve your problem here.

**UPDATE:** Concerning cases 1 and 2, this library can wrap all the magic http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/ and provide a cross-browser solution.